# how to use oracle database connection for jquery datatables server-side processing in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, datatables

I am using jquery datatables server-side processing example. But the class **ssp.class.php** they provide is built in with mysql database connection. I want to use oracle connection instead! Please help if possible. I have already tried an example here

http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_oracle

But it's showing oci related error though i successfully established a connection!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$conn=oci_connect('username', 'password', '//server/schema');
```

and remove or comment

```
/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']     = "";
$gaSql['password'] = "";
$gaSql['schema']   = "";
$gaSql['port']     = "";
$gaSql['server']   = "";

$connection_string = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = {$gaSql['server']  })(PORT = {$gaSql['port'] })))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID={$gaSql['schema']})))";
```

Comment: check this newer version of the datables php oracle connection http://pastebin.com/9AKcdWS6